# 2-step Authentication Facebook

Tags: facebook, multi-factor-auth, google-authenticator

I tried the 2-step authentication with Android's Authenticator app. It worked well, but then I removed the Facebook account from the Authenticator app and now I can't set it up again. Every time I try to add a Facebook account to the Authenticator app with the QR code (or manually), the security code won't be accepted by Facebook. I have tried to deactivate the code generator option in my Facebook settings, I have tried to log out and log in again, but nothing seem to help... Is there a possibility to let it work again?

[image]